# How to pass the variables from LWC component to chatbot variables in salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, chatbot, sfdc, salesforce-einstein

I have created one LWC component where the fields are First Name, Last Name, Email, and Country.
This LWC component I have added in the chatbot as a question.
When we submit the form the data is getting stored in one variable using postmessage.
I want to store the different fields in different variables like the first name from LWC to the First Name in the chatbot variable.

This is my component
[see the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hglA.png)

This is my line of code from where I am passing the message

let message = 'Your case number is '+':'+result + '\nfirstname' +' :'+this.ContactFirstName+'\nlastname'+':'+this.ContactLastName
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('postmessage',{
detail:'lwc:hide:'+message

message is getting displayed as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB3yS.png)

I want to separate first name and case number and stored different chatbot variables.